# One-to-many and one-to-one in Elixir Ecto at the same time

Tags: sql, database-design, elixir, ecto

I have 2 tables/schemas with relationship one-to-many, let's assume there is a `Person` that can have multiple `Animal`. Then each animal has person foreign key to implement this relationship. I use Elixir with Ecto, so it's straightforward for now and I have

```
schema "persons" do
  ...
  has_many :animals, Animal
end

schema "animals" do
  ...
  belongs_to :person, Person
end
```

I want to introduce the concept of person's favourite animal and each person can have at most 1 favourite animal (0 or 1). How to implement this second relationship between two tables when there is already one-to-many relationship?

Two alternative solutions come to my mind but neither is flawless.

1. Don't introduce one-to-one, but have another field in Animal named `favourite` with true or false. This is simple solution, but lacks database enforcement on having at most 1 favourite animal because there is possibility in DB for multiple animals of the same person to have `favourite: true` so there is a need to keep this constraint manually in business logic and continuously watch for it.
2. Introduce one-to-one relationship. Animal has already person_id_fkey, now I need to add animal_id_fkey to Person which indicates person's favourite animal. Intuition suggests me that person `has_one` favourite animal, but in Ecto we use `belongs_to` to introduce foreign key, so it comes as follows.

```
  ...
  has_many :animals, Animal
  belongs_to :favourite_animal, Animal
end

schema "animals" do
  ...
  belongs_to :person, Person
  has_one :person, Person <- this name must be different due to conflict
end
```

Verbs suggest that the person belongs to animal while the reality is quite different. Also there is ambiguity in field names - person has favourite animal, but how should this field `has_one Person` be named? It's not clear for me as more and more questions arises in the second scenario.

What is the idiomatic way in Ecto (or more generally in SQL) to solve such bi-directional foreign key relationship?

Comment: In relational databases, doubly linked associations aren't used as it messes with foreign keys. It would be more normal for an animal to belong to a person OR a person have an animal, but not both. In your case I'd have each person have zero-to-one favourite animal, and each animal belong to exactly-one person.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot test it right away, so I’m posting this as an answer for the sake of formatting only. Feel free to downvote if it does not work for you.

Verbs do not lie to you, simply use [`belongs_to/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#belongs_to/3) with proper options.

```elixir
schema "persons" do
  has_many :animals, Animal
  has_one :favorite, Animal
end

schema "animals" do
  belongs_to :person, Person, foreign_key: :owner_id, references: :id
  belongs_to :favorite_of_person, Person, foreign_key: :favorite_of_id, references: :id
end
```

Comment: Actually there can't multiple fields with the same name, so the second belongs_to would be `belongs_to :favourite_of_person`

Comment: Since the animal can be favourite of only one person (because it belongs to only one person) I have unique_constraint on animals table on the field `:favorite_of_person_id`. When I want to set another animal of the specific user to be his favourite I get unique_constraint error. Ecto seems not to support `ON CONFLICT SET NULL` for `Repo.update` which I call to set `favorite_of_person_id` on another animal. How to work it out?

Comment: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:insert/2-upserts

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use embed schemas? you can use embeds_many